# Why is PrinterSettings.Duplex not reporting what is set in Printing Preferences?

Tags: c#, .net, printing

In my application, we determine whether or not to insert page breaks between certain parts of a document based on whether or not the selected printer is set to duplex or simplex printing.

The standard .net [PrinterSettings class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.duplex%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) has a Duplex property. When we check it in the code, it is set to Simplex even though 2-sided printing (duplex printing) is selected in the printing preferences.

This check correctly reports the duplex setting for all other printers we have tested with, but is failing for one individual.

Not sure if it matters, but the printer is a Sharp brand network printer.

Basically, what I would like to know is if there are any other ways of checking the duplex setting, or any good ideas on how to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue with printer drivers, they'll report simplex regardless of settings.  Not so sure why they do this, I'm guessing it has something to do with the setting often being changed on the printer itself with the operator panel.  So they cannot reliably report the true setting since it may easily change after they reported the value.

Not much you can do about it, just make sure you select the setting you want before you print.  In other words, don't leave it up the printer, make the choice available in your UI.

Comment: I was afraid the answer would be along these lines. Ah well, yet another sad day in the sad, sad world of interfacing with printers. The worst part is that the application does not have a UI... Time to find the inevitable hacky workaround.